# Cannot run MariaDB within Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, mariadb

Whenever I try to run a MariaDB instance inside a Docker container, the startup fails with the error

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
Recreating matomo-mariadb_1 ... done
Attaching to matomo-mariadb_1
matomo-mariadb_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 340: exec: –: not found
```

The docker-compose.yml in question:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    command:
      – max-allowed-packet=64MB
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
        - /home/matomo/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

The directory "/home/matomo/data/mysql" has chmod -r 777 full access.

This seems to be an issue with the current Docker/Docker-Compose/MariaDB release because this happens on multiple devices with both Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 20.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Does the database already exist? Either way I'd try specifying MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD - the documentation says this is mandatory - and see if that helps.

Comment: Otherwise I'd take a look at /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh in the image and work out what's going on at line 340.

Answer (score 1):

You specified the command in a wrong format.

It should be either:

```
command: max-allowed-packet=64MB
```

or

```
command: ["max-allowed-packet=64MB"]
```

See the [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command).